# Configuring GCP Alerting for Business Hours Only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-monitoring

I am currently working on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Alerting for a specific use case. We have Compute Engine virtual machines (VMs) that are scheduled to run exclusively during business hours. Is there a way to configure the Monitoring and Alerting system to activate triggers and send notifications only within these designated business hours, while ignoring any triggers outside of this time frame?

Comment: Not sure if Monitoring has a built-in feature like that but the best thing I can think now is to set a cloud scheduler job that enables/disables the alert in the time you prefer

Answer (score 1):

As @Puteri said, it seems there is no inbuilt feature to configure alerts only for business hours But there is a work around which you can use to [snooze notifications and alerts](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/snooze). This will not create the alerts within the time interval you set to snooze. The only problem is that we need to do this daily if the alert should be snoozed only for a particular interval of a day. This snooze can support 7 days or even more but snoozes the entire hours.

As this is a valid feature and this can be useful to many, requesting you to raise a new request by using the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). The Google Product engineering team may enhance this feature.